# Can Bootstrap popovers not be destroyed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to have a bootstrap (v3) popovers to have it's div loaded right at the start of pageload and not be destroyed when it is being toggled?

I have a popover content in a div:

```
<div id="popoverContent">
<h1>Stuff</h1>
<p>I'm in a popover!</p>
</div>
```

And a button that toggles the popover:

```
<a id="floating_tab" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left">Button</a>
```

Here is my Javascript code that handles the button pushes:

```
<script>
var x = false;
$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
    content: $('#popoverContent').html(),
    html: true
}).click(function() {
  if (x) {
      $(this).popover('hide');
      x = false;
  }
  else {
    $(this).popover('show');
    x = true;
  }
});
</script>
```

The thing is, that when `$(this).popover('show');` is called, a div is created. Something like this shows up in the inspect element (chrome):

```
<div class="popover fade left in" role="tooltip" id="popover460185" style="top: 430.5px; left: 2234px; display: block;"><div class="arrow" style="top: 50%;"></div><h3 class="popover-title" style="display: none;"></h3><div class="popover-content">
  <h1>Stuff</h1>
  <p>I'm in a popover!</p>
</div></div>
```

But when the button is clicked again, the whole div itself is removed and obliterated from the page.
Is it possible to have the popover div to be created during pageload (hidden though) and can be toggleable without having the div to be deleted?

Comment: Why does it matter and what specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to have an audio inside the popoverContent div. When someone have it playing, it keeps playing, even if they closed the popover (or navigate to a different page, which I did have that working with AJAX). But when you close the popover on the page, the audio stops playing. I need a solution that keeps the audio loaded, even with the popover closed.

Comment: Can't keep audio playing if you navigate to another page. Can only do that in a single page app

Comment: I already had it working with the audio playing with different pages (ajax - http://mane-frame.com/). I just need to keep the popover "loaded."

Comment: Create your own using their styles

Comment: Bootstrap does not offer this functionality. The Popover (which is an extension of the Tooltip) is generated dynamically on each`show` call -and does not presently offer a solution for passing in pre-defined HTML -a plugin would need to be written.  The `hide` method uses `jQuery.detach` which removes the element from the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, it is not presently possible with Bootstrap 3. The Popover (which is an extension of the Tooltip) is dynamically created on `show` and detached (using `jQuery.detach`) from the DOM on `hide`.

It is probably best to roll your own JavaScript and simply utilize Bootstrap's CSS. However, you could easily patch the functionality using the Popover's event API -the following can be used as a starting place:

```
$(function () {

  var content = $('#popover-content'), // Pre defined popover content.
      popover = $('#popover-anchor').popover();

  popover.on('inserted.bs.popover', function () {
    var instance = $(this).data('bs.popover');
    // Replace the popover's content element with the 'content' element
    instance.$tip = content;
  });

  popover.on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    var instance = $(this).data('bs.popover');
    // Remove the reference to 'content', so that it is not detached on hide
    instance.$tip = null;
  });

  popover.on('hide.bs.popover', function () {
    // Manually hide the popover, since we removed the reference to 'content' 
    content.removeClass('in');
    content.addClass('out');
  });

});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/jtrumbull/pen/PNoVJX?editors=0010)